# Node can't find IP module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use the [IP module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip) in a Node program. However, whenever I try to add it in using `const ip = require("ip")`, I get the following error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'ip'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/fin444/Desktop/node/app.js:1:207)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
```

Why is this happening? I have installed and reinstalled the latest version of IP several times globally on my computer, and all other Node modules work fine.

Comment: What path did you install it in?

Comment: How exactly did you install it?  What exact command line did you use to install it?

Comment: I installed it using `sudo npm install ip -g` (without `sudo` it doesn't have permissions to save to my global modules directory). I see no reason it wouldn't install to the default node modules directory, as I haven't modified the path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  npm uninstall ip -g --save
```

Then:

```
  npm install ip -g --save
```

I don't know if --save is required anymore but I have had the issue that without this flag the module could not be found. Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, `--save` didn't seem to do it.